# Failing to authenticate BlobServiceClient and Azure AD

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm having issues using bloblserviceClient with azure Ad

I'm logged into account "X" in visual studio and also tools => optios => azure service authentication = account "X"

This is the following code

```
var uri = new Uri("https://testblob112.blob.core.windows.net/order");

var cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var client = new BlobClient(uri, cred);

await client.UploadAsync("test.txt");
```

User X also has Storage contributor access to the storage account order.

I'm getting the following error

> ure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: AADSTS9002332: Application 'e406a681-f3d4-42a8-90b6-c2b029497af1'(Azure Storage) is configured for use by Azure Active Directory users only. Please do not use the /consumers endpoint to serve this request.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you share the authority endpoint defined in your application configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Key access may be disabled.

Can you check these two options under Configuration in your Storage Account?

[image]

Comment: Both are enabled for the storage account.